# Magento 2 : Error 503 first byte timeout

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, catalog, massaction

Getting this error when i'm update product from product grid using update attributes.

[image]

Error Page:

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by Varnish limits. Try to increase your `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` in your **php.ini** and **pub/.user.ini** files.

If you use Fastly, navigate to **admin -> stores -> configuration -> Advance -> System -> Full Page Cache**, set Admin path timeout to 600, and click on **"Upload VCL to Fastly"**, this will increase the first-byte timeout in Fastly (600 is the max).

[image: Magento 2 - Fastly Admin path timeout to 600]

Answer (score 0):

Same error had happened to me , it is happening because of execution time out , you can increase it for magento by using `ini_set()` in `app/bootstrap.php`.

Update attributes also consumes a lot of memory depending on the number of products selected so you may also want to increase memory limit.

So, finally paste following code at the top of `app/bootstrap.php`

```
ini_set('memory_limit' , -1);
ini_set ( 'max_execution_time', 18000);
```